# Would multiple connection.query()-s slow the connection in node.js/mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have this website that uses the same queries over and over. I thought of creating small functions, passing the connection and other arguments to it, and reusing the functions.
For example, here's a typical way of using multiple statements:

```
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM customers; SELECT * FROM orders;", (err, rows) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);

        const customers = rows[0];
        const orders = rows[1];

        return {
            customers,
            orders
        }
    })
    connection.release()
})
```

However, let's assume I will be reusing the same queries over and over. Hence, I can do something like this:

```
const getCustomers = (connection, callback) => {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM customers;", (err, customers) => {
        if(err) return callback(err, null);

        return callback(null, customers)
    })
}

const getOrders = (connection, callback) => {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM orders;", (err, orders) => {
        if(err) return callback(err, null);

        return callback(null, orders)
    })
}

pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);

    getCustomers(connection, (err, customers) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);

        getOrders(connection, (err, orders) => {
            if(err) return console.log(err);

            return {
                customers,
                orders
            }
        })
    })
    connection.release()
})
```

So would using multiple connections slow down the server? Rather 1 connection that has multiple queries? Also, is this the correct way to use [this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) library? is `connection.release()` used properly?

Comment: Don't worry about prematurely optimizing the server interaction. Are you really retrieving all customers and orders separate? Do you need them all? If you need customer->order correlated use a `JOIN`. What is the size of these two tables? It looks like you're not using SQL to do the things its really good at and are going to do those things in your own code.

Comment: @danblack no no, it's just a mere random example, yes I do know all about queries and doing `JOIN` queries. There are many queries that I reuse multiple times over and over to do verifications on my website. And thank you for your answer.

Comment: How exactly would doing multiple sequential queries on the same connection slow down the connection? And are you asking about slowing down the connection (your title), or the server (your question)?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Both, I'm just concerned about the speed the server returns data from the DB.